# Какого человека называют косноязыким или косноязычным?

Tags: значение-слов

Прочитал вопрос о том, как называть человека, который не может говорить правильно, и сперва хотел предложить вариант "косноязычный", но потом задумался: а подходит ли это слово под данное определение? Мне кажется, что косноязычным можно назвать как раз того, кого в одном из ответов предложили обозвать "черномырдинцем" - то есть, человека неглупого, но плохо умеющего выражать свои мысли вслух.
Права ли я? Действительно ли определение "косноязычный" не подходит для "человека (либо самого явления) с низкой культурой речи, косноязычным слогом, скудным словарным запасом"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У слова "косноязычие" два основных значения. Во-первых, это невнятная речь, неспособность правильно произносить звуки. В этом случае человек говорит  неотчетливо, неразборчиво, нечленораздельно. "Мямля он и заика, каша у него во рту," - скажут наши добросердечные люди.

Во-вторых, это неумение грамотно, четко и красиво построить свою речь. Именно это отметят окружающие: косноязычный, двух слов связать не может.

Почему - это не важно. Возможно, перед нами  человек неразвитый, неначитанный и неинтеллектуальный. Или, может быть, что он хорошо владеет только письменной речью, а устная ему дается с трудом. А возможно, он даже будущий гений, со своими особенностями мыслительной деятельности. Вспомним, что косный - это отнюдь не косой, а просто поздний, запаздывающий, медлительный. Вот, к примеру, Альберт Эйнштейн очень поздно начал говорить и отличался плохой речью.

Но всё это детали, разбираться в которых никто не будет.

Comment: Позвольте напомнить: Эйнштейн был аутистом.

Comment: Как знать, разные есть мнения. Вот, например: "Дело сделано, два величайших физика (Эйнштейн и Ньютон) на весь мир объявлены больными людьми.Так это или не так, не суть важно, потому что теперь никто не докажет обратного. Осталось разобраться таким же образом со столпами древности - Аристотелем и Птолемеем (с Архимедом все ясно - бегал по улицам в голом виде, был неадекватен в момент своего убийства) и кое с кем из современников типа Ландау, Бора и пр.". http://physics-animations.com/miptboard/themes/1362.html

Comment: Я бы привела тут пример Моисея. В Писании сказано, что он был косноязычным - у него плохо получалось произносить речи, поэтому не мог проповедовать то, что ему давал Бог. И за него это делал его брат Аарон, у которого ораторское мастерство было проявлено на порядок лучше.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki  . Моисей был косноязычным не в силу умственной ограниченности , а в силу того , что он , будучи "подкидышем" , воспитывался во дворце фараона , горорил по-египетски (коптский язык) , и иврит не был его родным языком . Уже только в зрелом возрасте Моисей осознал себя евреем , но иврит полностью освоить не сумел . Поэтому ему требовался переводчик - Аарон .