# «Злоязычный» или «злоязыкий», «бескостноязычный» или «бескостноязыкий»?

Tags: вариативное-написание

> ...Не могу не вспомнить главного разрушителя якунинских разоблачений
> агента КГБ "Аббата" - Михалкова Н. С. Так артистично. Так
> малоаргументированно. Он весь такой за Царя, за Родину, за Веру
> вздумал в прямом эфире переговорить Ирину Дмитриевну Прохорову,
> литературоведа и редактора.
>
> Обоим палец в рот не клади, бедную ведущую посиделок чуть ли не локтем
> в угол задвинули, догадливый оператор сообразил, кто тут правит бал, и
> совсем убрал растерявшуюся бедняжку из кадра;
>
> и вот, слово за слово, Никита Сергеич произносит: "воцерковлённый",
> Иринка, ещё хвостик слова недозвучал: "воцеркОвленный", Никитка, к
> ужасу своему, понимает, что **бескостноязыкая** Ирка не может ошибиться...
> и захлёбывается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разве не достаточно последнего предложения как иллюстрации к вопросу об одном только слове? И автора на сцену надо бы...

Comment: что такое "бескостноязыкая/бескосноязыкая"?

Comment: https://azbyka.ru/katehizacija/kakaya-raznica-mezhdu-vocerkovlennymi-i-nevocerkovlennymi-xristianami-chto-oznachaet-slovo-vocerkovlennyj.shtml - на азбуке воцерковлённый, даже написано через Ё.

Comment: Буратинко! Где ни попадя и кто ни попадя - несерьёзные источники. )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• Последний абзац я бы оформила так:

> И вот, слово за слово, Никита Сергеич произносит: **"Воцерковлённый".** Иринка (ещё хвостик слова **не** дозвучал): **"Воцерко́вленный".** Никитка, к ужасу своему, понимает, что **бескосноязыкая** Ирка не может ошибиться... и захлёбывается.

У Ефремовой:
[косноязы́кий](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/177877/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) — ***разг**. прил.*; = косноязычный.
[Отличающийся неумелым построением фраз, плохим стилем (о тексте, речи и т. п.)]

Стиль повествования разговорный, поэтому, думаю, можно использовать любой неологизм.

• В толковом словаре Ефремовой (без пометок):
[злоязы́чный](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/168686/%D0%97%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) — 1. Зло, язвительно говорящий о ком-либо или о чём-либо. 2. Склонный к злословию, пересудам. 3. Преисполненный злобы, язвительности.
[злоязы́кий](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/168680/%D0%97%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) — 1. Зло, язвительно говорящий о ком-либо или о чём-либо. 2. Склонный к злословию, сплетням, пересудам.

О прилагательном "злоязычный": в словаре Ушакова (1935–1940) — *книжн. устар.*, у Ожегова — *устар.*
Так что для нейтрального стиля лучше *косноязычный*, но — *злоязыкий*.

Comment: Не могу понять: бескосноязыкая или бескостноязыкая?  Поясните, пожалуйста, смысл слов.

Comment: Язык у ей без костей.

Answer (score 1):

В общем:

Патриарх Кирилл говорит "[воцерковлЁнные](https://ok.ru/video/1925472195027)"(3:55)

Осипов тоже говорит воцерковлЁнный(9:14):"... я воцерковлЁн, вот так." - "[Воцерковлённость это ещё не духовность!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbzOk7U875A&t=73s) (Отдел доп. образования ОДО МДА, 05.08.2023) / А.И. Осипов"

Про корректность словообразования "бескосн(т)ноязычный/-кий" в любой форме, я вообще сомневаюсь. Например, есть слово "малограмотный", но безмалограмтный не говорят. Вообще употребление приставки бес- со сложными(не аббривеатурными) словами... может вы знаете, есть ли такие? Мне кажется таких нет. То есть нет слов вроде: безводопроводный, безземлевладельческий, безживотрепещущий, бессвежемороженный, бессильнодействующий(хотя есть бессильный и бездействующий) и тп. Хотя, вроде бы можно - бесколхозный или бесЦИПСОшный, но я не уверен.

про слово косно+язычный, косно - не от слова кость, а от слова касаться. Человек не умеющий выразить мысли в чёткой языковой форме, а говорящий около образами, пользующийся косвенными указаниями, либо заика, тот кого надо понимать с полуслова: - Там л-л-лошадь, у-у-пал-л-ла н-на улице Г-г-г-г... г-г-г... - Герцена? -Н-н-н-ет.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152219/discussion-on-answer-by-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

**Дополнительный материал по теме**

```
                Язык у ей без костей.
```

1. **Воцерковленный или воцерковлённый?**

**Русский орфографический словарь:**
воцеркОвленный; кр. ф. -ен, -ена

**Википедия**

```
  Воцерко́вленный (от церковь; воцерковлённый — 
  неправильно[1]) — церковный термин, который используется в 
  практике Русской Православной Церкви и в околоцерковных 
  кругах, а также в других религиозных организациях. Он 
  имеет два значения, одно — терминологически точное 
  обозначение определённого обряда, другое — переносное, 
  связанное с особенностями современной церковной жизни.
```

Обсуждение в Сети. **[Ударение «воцеркОвленный»](https://akvech.livejournal.com/198864.html)**

Мы, как всегда, **хорошо не понимаем** друг друга))

```
  Я неоднократно слышал это слово, но всегда во варианте 
  «воцерковлЁнный». Забавно, что даже моя православная 
  подруга никогда не слышала вариант «воцеркОвленный» и 
  утверждает, что и от священников слышала только вариант 
  «воцерковлЁнный», который словарями вроде как не 
  признаётся литературным. Мёртвая литературная норма?
```

**Вежливый комментарий** от пользователя:

```
   Ты раскопал дохлятину, чувак, у тебя просто нюх на нее.
```

2. **Бескостноязыкий или бескосноязыкий**?

Авторский неологизм, но что он означает: **язык без костей** или **некосноязыкий**?

***Косноязыкий*** — это разговорный вариант (правильно ***косноязычный***). От языка без костей ничего не осталось.  Сложно  тему понять! К тому же эти парные слова (***СН*** или ***СТН***) — вечная проблема в орфографии, да еще семантика самого слова ***косноязычный*** не всегда однозначно понимается.

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34765/Какого-человека-называют-косноязыким-или-косноязычным](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34765/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC)